# @Input() hero: Hero;

Tags: angular2, typescript

Здравствуйте.

Решил учить Angular 4 и следую туториалу на сайте https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3 
Но, в который раз возник вопрос. 
Что это за конструкция @Input() hero: Hero;
Для чего она? Что оно делает?

Вот код.
hero-details.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from "./hero";


@Component({
 selector: 'hero-detail',
 templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html'
})
export class HeroDetailComponent {
 @Input() hero: Hero;
}
```

Вот еще код для файлов
app.components.ts, app.components.html, hero-details.components.html
http://prntscr.com/g9ousk

Объясните пожалуйста, если кто может.

Comment: Декоратор, чтоб на него биндиться можно было.

Answer (score 1):

`@Input hero: Hero` объявляет объект типа `Hero`, который принимается из вне компонента:

```
<hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero">
```

в данном случаи selectedHero будет передан в компонент и тот сможет использовать его свойства.

Comment: _"двухсторонне-связанный"_ - с чего бы?

Comment: @Qwertiy в том смысле, что это будет тот же связанный объект, что и вне его. Параметры не будут копиями, а на них можно повесить бинды, менять внутри шаблона компонента и т.д И все это отразится на скоупах, где объект используется. Может поправите, чтобы более корректно это выразить.

Comment: Это однонаправленный биндинг.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему? Его можно поменять и в UI и в логике компонента.

Comment: Думаю он однонаправленный из родительского компонента в дочерний. И что если его изменить в дочернем компоненте, то он не измениться в родительском.

Comment: @НазарКалитюк по ссылке выше из доки как раз пример и делает это. В hero-detail меняется объект и автоматом меняется отображение в основном списке. https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/toh-pt3/eplnkr.html

Comment: @tcpack4, он не меняет ссылку.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да. О том и речь, он отдает ссылкой, а не копирует параметры.

Comment: @tcpack4, он однонаправленно отдаёт ссылку.

Comment: @Qwertiy ссылка и есть ссылка. В базовом примере он взаимодействует с родительским скоупом. Каким образом вы представляется противоположность "однонаправленной отдачи ссылки" в данном контексте?

Comment: @tcpack4, `this.hero = {}` - вот если так изменится в родительском - то это был бы двунаправленныей биндинг. Пример двунаправленного биндинга в ангуляре: `<input [(ngModel)]="smth" />`. А по отдельности `[]` и `()` - это однонаправленные биндинги, только в разные стороны.

Comment: @Qwertiy ок, спс, протупил)